# How to install libpython2.7.so

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, centos, system-administration

I have installed Python 2.6.6 at

```
[17:50:21 root@data.dev:~]# which python
/usr/local/bin/python
```

also Python 2.7.6 at

```
[17:51:12 root@data.dev:~]# which python2.7
/usr/local/bin/python2.7
```

But libpython2.7.so is missing

```
[17:48:52 root@data.dev:~]# locate libpython2.6.so
/usr/lib64/libpython2.6.so
/usr/lib64/libpython2.6.so.1.0
/usr/lib64/python2.6/config/libpython2.6.so
[17:48:56 root@data.dev:~]# locate libpython2.7.so
[17:49:02 root@data.dev:~]#
```

Dont know how to fix this.

can anyone help ?

Comment: Have you updated locate's database? You need to run `updatedb` to regenerate the database.
You could also try to do `ldconfig -p | grep python2.7`

Comment: it doesn't show anything for `ldconfig -p | grep python2.7`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could try compiling it from sources, in root :

```
yum -y install python-devel openssl openssl-devel gcc sqlite-devel

wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.5/Python-2.7.5.tar.bz2
tar -xvjf Python-2.7.5.tar.bz2
cd Python-2.7.5
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/python2.7 --with-threads --enable-shared
make
make install altinstall

ln -s /usr/local/python2.7/lib/libpython2.7.so /usr/lib
ln -s /usr/local/python2.7/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0 /usr/lib
ln -s /usr/local/python2.7/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/bin
/sbin/ldconfig -v
```

Then test getting correct python
    /usr/local/python2.7/bin/python2.7 -V

And, as normal user :

```
echo "alias python='/usr/local/python2.7/bin/python2.7'" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
python -V
```

Good luck :)

Comment: I dont want to make 2.7 default Python. i want to keep default to 2.6. So do I need do any changes ?

Comment: Now I have another trouble. i am not able to install pip packages for 2.7. any idea how to do this ?

Comment: Thanks.. this helped :)

Comment: Please, don't. Compile stuff yourself and replace system binaries is not recommended at all, unless you fully understand what your're doing.

Comment: Recompile python source code and install did not help, the problem is solved until soft links are created according to your solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev

Answer (score 0):

For Pip you need openssl, Please install the below pkgs , before you go for pip
openssl.x86_64
openssl-devel.x86_64