# Python Cannot Locate libpython2.7.so.1.0

Tags: python, centos

All the operations are done on an offline system. (Centos)
When I download and decompress anaconda2, I moved python and python2.7 file to /usr/bin/python. However, after trying to start python, it shows:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libpython2.7.so.1.0:cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The result of `locate libpython2.7.so.1.0` cannot tell the directory of this file.

Considering that this machine is offline, is there any viable solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install libpython2.7.so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26597527/how-to-install-libpython2-7-so)

Comment: Under this scenario, I cannot use yum nor pip since the computer is offline. yum is corrupted since this particular file is absent